# Android get json from webhost to add markers ERROR E/zygote64

Tags: java, android, json, google-maps, android-studio

i am making one project example to get json coordinates from 000webhost and show marks in maps in Android.
This is my java main code:

```
public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback,LocationListener,GoogleMap.OnMarkerClickListener  {

private GoogleMap mMap;
public static final String URL="http://rrsaikat.mydiscussion.net/myjson/location.php";
private JSONArray result;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);

    SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
    mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
}

@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    mMap = googleMap;
    googleMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL);

    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
            && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
    {
        return;
    }
    mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);

    RequestQueue requestQueue= Volley.newRequestQueue(getApplicationContext());
    StringRequest stringRequest=new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, URL, new Response.Listener<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {
            Log.d("JSONResult" , response.toString());
            JSONObject j = null;
            try{
                j =new JSONObject(response);
                result = j.getJSONArray("FL");
                for(int i=0;i<result.length();i++){
                    JSONObject jsonObject1=result.getJSONObject(i);
                    String lat_i = jsonObject1.getString("1");
                    String long_i = jsonObject1.getString("2");

                    mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                            .position(new LatLng(Double.parseDouble(lat_i) , Double.parseDouble(long_i)))
                            .title(Double.valueOf(lat_i).toString() + "," + Double.valueOf(long_i).toString())
                            .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_RED))
                    );

                    mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(new LatLng(23.6850,90.3563), 6.0f));
                }

            }catch (NullPointerException e){
                e.printStackTrace();

            }

            catch (JSONException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            error.printStackTrace();
            Toast.makeText(MapsActivity.this, error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });

    int socketTimeout = 10000;
    RetryPolicy policy = new DefaultRetryPolicy(socketTimeout, DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_MAX_RETRIES, DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT);
    stringRequest.setRetryPolicy(policy);
    requestQueue.add(stringRequest);

}

@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {

}

@Override
public void onStatusChanged(String s, int i, Bundle bundle) {

}

@Override
public void onProviderEnabled(String s) {

}

@Override
public void onProviderDisabled(String s) {

}

@Override
public boolean onMarkerClick(Marker marker) {
    return false;
}
```

But i dont have the marks in Android and i have this debug:

> W/zygote64: Skipping duplicate class check due to unrecognized classloader I/DynamiteModule: Considering local module
>   com.google.android.gms.maps_dynamite:0 and remote module
>   com.google.android.gms.maps_dynamite:220 I/DynamiteModule: Selected
>   remote version of com.google.android.gms.maps_dynamite, version >= 220
>   W/zygote64: Skipping duplicate class check due to unrecognized
>   classloader I/Google Maps Android API: Google Play services client
>   version: 12451000 I/Google Maps Android API: Google Play services
>   package version: 12685023 I/zygote64: Do partial code cache
>   collection, code=23KB, data=29KB
>               After code cache collection, code=23KB, data=29KB
>               Increasing code cache capacity to 128KB E/zygote64: The String#value field is not present on Android versions >= 6.0
>   D/NetworkSecurityConfig: No Network Security Config specified, using
>   platform default I/System.out: (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled
>   false I/System.out: (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
>   I/zygote64: Do partial code cache collection, code=61KB, data=59KB
>   D/TcpOptimizer: TcpOptimizer-ON I/zygote64: After code cache
>   collection, code=61KB, data=59KB
>               Increasing code cache capacity to 256KB D/ViewRootImpl@82b5652[MapsActivity]: setView =
>   DecorView@42ced23[MapsActivity] TM=true MM=false
>   D/ViewRootImpl@4f69478[Launcher]: MSG_WINDOW_FOCUS_CHANGED 0
>   D/ViewRootImpl@82b5652[MapsActivity]: dispatchAttachedToWindow
>   V/Surface: sf_framedrop debug : 0x4f4c, game : false, logging : 0
>   D/ViewRootImpl@82b5652[MapsActivity]: Relayout returned:
>   old=[0,0][0,0] new=[0,0][1080,2220] result=0x7 surface={valid=true
>   490213584896} changed=true D/mali_winsys: EGLint
>   new_window_surface(egl_winsys_display *, void *, EGLSurface,
>   EGLConfig, egl_winsys_surface **, egl_color_buffer_format *,
>   EGLBoolean) returns 0x3000,  [1080x2220]-format:1 D/OpenGLRenderer:
>   eglCreateWindowSurface = 0x7230f51fa0
>   D/ViewRootImpl@82b5652[MapsActivity]: MSG_RESIZED_REPORT:
>   frame=Rect(0, 0 - 1080, 2220) ci=Rect(0, 63 - 0, 0) vi=Rect(0, 63 - 0,
>   0) or=1
>                                         MSG_WINDOW_FOCUS_CHANGED 1 V/InputMethodManager: Starting input:
>   tba=android.view.inputmethod.EditorInfo@9c8881 nm :
>   com.a9831.sapires.samuel9831 ic=null I/InputMethodManager:
>   startInputInner - mService.startInputOrWindowGainedFocus V/Surface:
>   sf_framedrop debug : 0x4f4c, game : false, logging : 0 V/Surface:
>   sf_framedrop debug : 0x4f4c, game : false, logging : 0 D/mali_winsys:
>   EGLint new_window_surface(egl_winsys_display *, void *, EGLSurface,
>   EGLConfig, egl_winsys_surface **, egl_color_buffer_format *,
>   EGLBoolean) returns 0x3000,  [1080x2157]-format:2 D/OpenGLRenderer:
>   eglDestroySurface = 0x7242c28a00 D/ViewRootImpl@4f69478[Launcher]:
>   Relayout returned: old=[0,0][1080,2220] new=[0,0][1080,2220]
>   result=0x5 surface={valid=false 0} changed=true I/System.out:
>   (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false I/System.out:
>   (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
>   D/ViewRootImpl@4f69478[Launcher]: dispatchDetachedFromWindow
>   D/InputEventReceiver: channel 'f8f1abc
>   com.a9831.sapires.samuel9831/com.a9831.sapires.samuel9831.Launcher
>   (client)' ~ Disposing input event receiver.
>                         channel 'f8f1abc com.a9831.sapires.samuel9831/com.a9831.sapires.samuel9831.Launcher
>   (client)' ~NativeInputEventReceiver. I/zygote64: Do full code cache
>   collection, code=124KB, data=118KB I/zygote64: After code cache
>   collection, code=111KB, data=63KB W/DynamiteModule: Local module
>   descriptor class for com.google.android.gms.googlecertificates not
>   found. I/DynamiteModule: Considering local module
>   com.google.android.gms.googlecertificates:0 and remote module
>   com.google.android.gms.googlecertificates:4
>                     Selected remote version of com.google.android.gms.googlecertificates, version >= 4 W/zygote64:
>   Skipping duplicate class check due to unrecognized classloader
>   I/zygote64: Do partial code cache collection, code=122KB, data=79KB
>   I/zygote64: After code cache collection, code=122KB, data=79KB
>               Increasing code cache capacity to 512KB I/zygote64: Compiler allocated 4MB to compile void
>   com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.gmm6.vector.bs.b(javax.microedition.khronos.opengles.GL10)
>   I/System.out: (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false I/System.out:
>   (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false V/InputMethodManager:
>   Starting input: tba=android.view.inputmethod.EditorInfo@b8feb38 nm :
>   com.a9831.sapires.samuel9831 ic=null I/InputMethodManager:
>   startInputInner - mService.startInputOrWindowGainedFocus
>   D/ViewRootImpl@82b5652[MapsActivity]: performDraw() was skipped by
>   AOD_SHOW_STATE... DisplayState=3 D/ViewRootImpl@82b5652[MapsActivity]:
>   MSG_WINDOW_FOCUS_CHANGED 0 D/OpenGLRenderer: eglDestroySurface =
>   0x7230f51fa0

The only RED error is:

> E/zygote64: The String#value field is not present on Android versions >= 6.0

but the program dont stop and work but withou Markers.
Thks in advance